# jQuery's appendTo Creates Duplicate List Items in Mobile Browser

Tags: jquery, list, appendto

I have the following very simple code using jQuery to append dynamically created items to a list:

```
var keywords = ["word1", "word2", "word3", ...];
$.each(keywords, function(index, keyword) {
    var searchResultHTML = "<li id=" + index + ">" + search(keyword) + "</li>";
    $(searchResultHTML).appendTo("#search_result_list");
});
```

Above codes work fine in all major desktop browsers. However, in mobile browsers like iPad/iPhone, the generated list always contains duplicated items. What could go wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: whether all the elements are duplicated? if yes are they repeated in the same order like `"word1", "word2", "word3"...` then again `"word1", "word2", "word3",...`

Comment: the duplication looks like: word1 word1 word2 word2 word3 word3...

Comment: Use iPad or iPhone to visit: http://ec2-50-112-176-169.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, and type in some drug names and click the button.

Comment: @GranvilleXiong how is the site supposed to work? I typed in word and pressed enter as well as tried the Add button but nothing happens.  What am I missing?

Comment: just type one or two letters, then a list of matched names will pop up, and select any one of them and the selected one will enter the list view below. After adding a few names, just click the check button below. Query results will show at the right hand side.

Comment: After some debugging, I found the bug: the response to both click and touchstart events makes the search function be called twice! Thank you all!